# Dynamically get random values from a set of values in xml

Tags: javascript, html, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am now in need of getting some random values from a list of values in XML. Let me explain it clearly. consider it as my XML.

```
<data>
    <value>
        <name>a</name>
        <age>1</age>
    </value>
    <value>
        <name>b</name>
        <age>2</age>
    </value>
    <value>
        <name>c</name>
        <age>3</age>
    </value>
    <value>
        <name>d</name>
        <age>4</age>
    </value>
    <value>
        <name>e</name>
        <age>5</age>
    </value>
</data>
```

i have to parse 3 values dynamically in a random manner. i.e. if a,b,c are displayed once the next time when the page loaded it has to display d,b,e or any other in a random order. How i have to deal with it.

Comment: I havent tried anything. I know xml parsing. I need some script for randomly generating values

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119218/xpath-select-a-child-node-at-random) post?

Comment: Thanks for the link. Am newbie to Html and Javascript. Am not gettin any idea from that. Sorry for that

Comment: I suggest you use the DOMParser ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOMParser), [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-DOM-Level-3-LS-20030619/load-save.html#LS-DOMParser)) to turn the XML into a document, then display 3 random value elements. Or hide all but 3 random value elements, whatever.

Comment: @RobG its too complicated i think As a newbie to web tech. There is some simple way. Hoping for that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to convert a string of XML to a document. You can then use DOM methods on the document:

```
var stringToXMLDoc = (function(global) {

  // W3C DOMParser support
  if (global.DOMParser) {
    return function (text) {
      var parser = new global.DOMParser();
      return parser.parseFromString(text,"application/xml");
    }

  // MS ActiveXObject support
  } else {
    return function (text) {
      var xmlDoc;

      // Can't assume support and can't test, so try..catch
      try {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async="false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
      } catch (e){}
      return xmlDoc;
    }
  }
}(this));
```

Example:

```
var xml = '<books>' + 
            '<book title="foo"/>' +
            '<book title="bar"/>' +
            '<book title="baz"/>' +
          '</books>';
var doc = stringToXMLDoc(xml);
alert(
  doc.getElementsByTagName('book')[2].getAttribute('title')
);
```

You should be able to do something similar with the value nodes.